# while installing ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch

While installing Ubuntu phone I entered:

```
sudo fastboot oem unlock
```

It doesn't read the device and printed:

```
< waiting for device >
```

on the terminal. Note my device is genx GX Pad 370 G with android version 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu touch isn't available for this device

[Ubuntu touch Devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices)